# How to use Azure AD B2C as IdP for Amazon Cognito

Tags: azure, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate Azure AD B2C as IdP for Amazon Cognito

The only documentation that I found in the web is [this](https://dev.to/danielbayerlein/how-to-use-azure-ad-b2c-as-idp-for-amazon-cognito-28nj)

this is not helpful for me. How to set this up?

Comment: SO is  not a "documentation search service". Search furhere, e. g. [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-provider.html) or [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-integrate-third-party-idp-using-developer-authenticated-identities/)  You can configure an external IdP for the UserPool (OIDC or SAML). Azure AD supports both protocols as an IdP. For how to set it up, what have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: I understand that it's not a documentation search service and I have configured everything based on Microsoft azure docs and still it's not working.

I have added custom policies as well as user info endpoints

The problem is that I am not able to sign in with the registered user which I registered through the run URL provided in the custom policy UI in azure ad b2c

Answer (score 0):

The perfect doc for this is https://dev.to/danielbayerlein/how-to-use-azure-ad-b2c-as-idp-for-amazon-cognito-28nj

that I mentioned in my question itself. It's just that there were few more steps that needed to be figured out and now it is added in the blog itself